# Pandas read_csv() can not read the string "null"

Tags: python, pandas, csv

If I have this CSV :

```
"col1"
"hi"
```

it is read correctly using this code :

```
import pandas
df = pandas.read_csv("test.csv")
print(list(df["col1"]))
```

and prints :

```
['hi']
```

But if I change the string "hi" to "null" in the CSV , it fails !

It now prints

```
[nan]
```

My actual CSV is quite large and it so happened that it has this string "null" as a field value somewhere, and it cannot be read correctly it seems.

Any workarounds ?

Comment: what do you expect to have instead if `[nan]` ?

Comment: I would expect to have ["null"]

Comment: @Wartin I don't have time to answer properly right now - look at https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html - and then search that page for `na_values`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

using `keep_default_na` (see [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)) is the right way to go.

**Clumsy Solution below**

Using `replace` can do the job for you. Note that the current code  replace all `nan` values across the `df`.

You can replace only is specific columns by using

`df[['col1']] = df[['col1']].fillna('null')`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv("test.csv")
print('before:')
print(list(df["col1"]))

df = df.replace(np.nan, 'null', regex=True)
print('after:')
print(list(df["col1"]))
```

output

```
before:
[nan]
after:
['null']
```

Comment: Smart ! keep_default_na=False tested and worked , thank you.